# Как достать объекты из списка Json?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Получаю список:

```
 List<Post> posts = Collections.singletonList(response.body());
                for (Post post : posts) {
                    Log.e("asd", "" +  post.getPersonnel().get(0));
                }
```

И получаю вот такой ответ:

```
E/asd: {personnel_number=5555.0, first_name=Валерій, last_name=Валерій, middle_name=, id=1025228.0}
```

Как мне достать элементы?
Нужно знать значение каждого по отдельности!

Comment: а как вы используете Ретрофит, что ответ вам приходит в строке? он как раз и должен вашу строку превращать в объект класса. показывайте полный код.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Уже разобрался. Позже напишу как решил это.